# Facebook Graph API post, generate user notification on feed post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, post, facebook-group

I'm trying to post to a group via the /{group-id}/feed edge. This part works great, but it does not generate a notification to all the users in the group.

Anyone know how to do this? It kinda defeats the purpose of the app if I can't generate notification on a post.

Comment: why would it create a notification?

Comment: So that the users in the group know that there is a new post.

Comment: they will see it in their stream. or they will get a notification if they specifically set that option in the group settings. posting something in a group does not mean that everyone in the group should get notified just because you posted it. that would be weird.

Comment: Well I have the "all posts" selected as notification option for that group and it still doesn't give me a notification.
I do know that an access_token generated by/for the graph api does this, but i guess that's because it's facebook's own :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users have to set the option to get notifications in the group, else they don´t get a notification for new posts. In order to make new posts visible to all users, you need to take your App live in the "App Review" tab. If that still does not work, you should file a bug.